# How do you protect your bike from scratches?

Tags: paint, protection

Anyone here use protective tape to protect a new frame? To which areas do you apply the tape?  I have a new frame and I am worried that other bikes sharing bike racks will scratch my ride.

Comment: When you buy a new bike (or car) you should grab a convenient tool (hammer for a car, maybe a piece of rebar for a bike) AND JUST GET IT OVER WITH!!! Bikes (and cars) are tools, not museum pieces.

Comment: I have to agree with @Daniel R Hicks completely. You should spend the time worrying about your bike worrying about people who love you instead. A bike can be replaced, people can't ;)

Comment: Store it in a Museum in a glass case.

Comment: Sorry for question, I have asked the moderator to delete this post.

Comment: When my top tube kept getting scuffed up in the bike rack, I just wrapped it in black electrical tape to keep the paint from chipping off. But later I discovered 3M black reflectorized tape and replaced the electrical tape with reflectorized tape.

Comment: No need to delete the post. It's a valid question. But the responses in the comments are valid too. :)

Comment: I've used http://www.biketape.co.uk/pages/about-us quite effectively in the past. Keeps the bike shinier for longer which is quite a feat in the gritty mud we splash around in :)

Comment: @DanielRHicks, unless it's carbon. Don't hit carbon with a hammer.  :-)

Comment: Adhesive residue is easily removed with wd40 and a little elbow grease

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use helicopter tape. You can find it on Amazon or from most any race car supply shop. It's a little pricey but well worth it. It's very sticky and thick enough to absorb impacts from rocks. I use it on the bottom side of my downtube, on the drive side chain stay, and anywhere a cable is close to the frame.

Comment: Do they really use it on Helicopters? ;->

Comment: They actually do, it's designed to protect the leading edge of helicopter blades. You'd think if it can do that it can protect your carbon fiber from rock chips as well.

Comment: I assume there is fake knockoff helicopter tape being sold? How do you tell the difference?

Comment: The stuff I use is made by "ISC", it's the real deal. You can find it here on Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/ISC-Helicopter-OG-Surface-Tape-Outdoor/dp/B000TPC7HU/

Comment: Thanks, Found some by 3M....http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/cspages/8672.php

Comment: I endorse this, even on road bikes. Helicopter tape is clear, so it's not obvious. It is not actually that pricey these days (in 2023).

Answer (score 2):

A [protective covering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CK0O58) is useful on the chainstay if it is prone to frequent chainslap. Other than that, I'd say that it is worse to try to protect your frame with tape than to just allow it to get an occasional nick and scuff.

On a practical note, if you do get some paint chip on a steel frame it is a good idea to dab a little clear nail polish on it to prevent rust from getting started.

Finally, if the frame is worth it, you can always have it professionally powder-coated when the time comes. It is like having a new bike.

Comment: Clear nail polish is something that needs to be frequently re-applied, particularly in areas that get a lot of abuse. On bikes (and [on fingernails](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/acoustic-guitar-how-to-stop-right-index-finger-nail-from-wearing-away)).

Comment: It will cover a scratch and protect from rust just fine, until another scratch appears in exactly the same place. In any case, it is better than coating a bike with something akin to a grandmother's plastic sofa cover ! :-)

Comment: Now I'm imagining my 16" red folding bike covered with sofa covers. It would be adorable!

Answer (score 1):

Pieces of old inner tubes secured with painter's or electrician's tape.
Roll a few lengths of inner tube around the toptube as needed.
Also wrap innertube around your D lock to prevent scratches, or just keep some handy where you carry your good spare inner tube.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Did you ever have problems with the tape shrinking and the adhesive making a mess?   I've tweaked your grammar without changing the meaning.  Feel free to revert if I've misplaced or chaged your message.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy clear tape meant to fit your bike, or you can save some cash and fit some clear packing tape on the areas that are scratched the most.

Comment: it wont help from huge rock scraping, but it does the trick on most scratches and larger cosmetic  stuff