# How to protect underneath the frame?

Tags: frames, protection

I've searched and only found [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/how-do-you-protect-your-bike-from-scratches) and [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21121/protecting-carbon-bike-frame-after-a-small-chip). But what I am really after is on a solution on how to cover/protect the underside of your frame.

I have a carbon road bike with mostly a white painted scheme throughout the bottom side and it's starting to show small chips already. Is there some form of transparent coating (think PU or some other stick on plastic) that I could use, later remove once too damaged and replace again to give my frame more life?

Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get some [Factory Effex Frame Protection Material](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/factory-effex-frame-protection-material/rp-prod39319), It's a vinyl that you just stick to you frame. You can get it in Black, **Clear**, or Carbon.

[image]

Comment: @FandangoAus - You're welcome, but plan on not getting it on there perfectly the first time, you may need to figure out what shape to cut it and how to form it to your frame. I recommend using a heat gun or hair dryer too.

Answer (score 0):

I use hockey tape to protect my right chain stay from chain slap. One inch wide by 98 feet of tape for less than 3 bucks! Should work well for what you need?

http://www.hockeymonkey.com/hockeytape.html